# Recurrent Neural network in Erlang

Tags: erlang, recurrent-neural-network, erlang-nif

I am currently working on an erlang project and need to create a game bot as a side feature. But to my surprise I was unable to find a single library  that I can use to create RNN in erlang. 
What should I do? How do I implement RNN in erlang? Is is even possible? Any module/library you are aware of that might help me do the task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/lfex/lsci Calls into pylibs. You can call into tensorflow or such.

Comment: http://blog.ikura.co/posts/yanni-sings.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Erlang is not very well suited for heavy number-crunching when RNN is basically a lot of matrix multiplications and other operations but is very well suited to use existing libraries as NIFs. So you can be the first one who will make one.